# Regex replace the nth element from string and adding custom HTML Tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of words `"this", "be able", "it"` that I want to find inside a paragraph so I can replace preserving their capitalization.

Having this paragraph:

> This is my text and this is why I want to match it! As this is just a
>   text, I would like to be able to solve it. This is the final phrase of
>   this paragraph.

`"this"` is found 5 times and if I decide to replace the 4th one (`"This"`) I want to still be able to keep the T capital. Now you will see that's not actually a replace but more of an adding problem as the actual replace would be from `this` to **`This`**

so my final paragraph would be:

> This is my text and this is why I want to match it! As this is just a text, I would like to be able to solve it. **This** is the final phrase of this paragraph.

My code so far:

```
    List<string> words = new List<string>(new string[] { "this", "be able", "it"});
    var paragraph = "This is my text and this is why I want to match it! As this is just a text, I would like to be able to solve it. This is the final phrase of this paragraph.";
    //List<string> 
    for (int w = 0; w < words.Count; w++)
    {
        var foudItems = Regex.Matches(paragraph, @"\b" + words[w] + "\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (foudItems.Count != 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int rndWord = rnd.Next(0, foudItems.Count);
            Regex.Replace(paragraph, @"\b" + words[w] + "\\b", "<strong>" + foudItems[rndWord] + "</strong>");
            Console.WriteLine(paragraph);
        }

        //Regex.Replace()
        Console.WriteLine(foudItems[0] + " " + foudItems[1]);
}
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to replace only the n'th word using regex. Another issue would be the complicated approach in solving this so I'm open to new suggestions.

Comment: Beware http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: It's not clear to me what purpose your code has. Can you explain a bit more about that "4th occurrence" thing? Do you want to highlight only one occurrence? If yes, what's the point of the other search terms? And what is the random number in your code supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace nth occurrence of something, you can use `MatchEvaluator` delegate which checks current occurrence index and returns unmodified matched value if index match is not one you want to replace. To track current index you can capture local variable:

```
int occurrenceToReplace = 4;
int index = 0;
MatchEvaluator evaluator = m => (++index == occurrenceToReplace)
    ? $"<strong>{m.Value}</strong>"
    : m.Value;

text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\bthis\b", evaluator, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

---

Now back to your problem - you can write method which wraps nth occurrence of given word into html tag:

```
private static string MakeStrong(string text, string word, int occurrence)
{
    int index = 0;
    MatchEvaluator evaluator = m => (++index == occurrence)
         ? $"<strong>{m.Value}</strong>"
         : m.Value;
    return Regex.Replace(text, $@"\b{word}\b", evaluator, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

And if you want to randomly replace one of the occurrences of each word, then just use this method in a loop:

```
string[] words = { "this", "be able", "it"};   
var paragraph = @"This is my text and this is why I want to match it! As this is just
a text, I would like to be able to solve it. This is the final phrase of this paragraph.";

var random = new Random();
foreach(var word in words)
{
    int count = Regex.Matches(paragraph, $@"\b{word}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Count;
    int occurrence = random.Next(count + 1);
    paragraph = MakeStrong(paragraph, word, occurrence);
}
```

Sample output:

> This is my text and **this** is why I want to match
>   **it**! As this is just a text, I would like to
>   **be able** to solve it. This is the final phrase of this
>   paragraph.

Comment: Not necessary. Just use backrefs.

Comment: (Given that I understood the question as "the 4th occurrence should look like the input", not "I only want to replace the 4th occurrence".)

Comment: @Tomalak from given expected sample I see that only 4th occurrence should be wrapped with tags

Comment: Hmm... It's not what match highlighters typically do, hence my assumption. But yeah, in that case there is no way around a MatchEvaluator.

Comment: @Tomalak well, there is an option to skip symbols from input start, as Thomas suggested, but I would rather go with evaluator here :)

Comment: Yeah, that would be dirty. :) You should mention regex escaping. It's a common source of bugs and should be part of the basic scrutiny when dealing with dynamically built regex.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't as clear as I should have been but @SergeyBerezovskiy seems to be a mind-reader as he perfectly understood what I wanted to accomplish and offered an understandable explanation wrapped around an elegant solution.Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the regex side quite simple, you can use this algo:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>(new string[] { "this", "be able", "it" });
var paragraph = "This is my text and this is why I want to match it! As this is just a text, I would like to be able to solve it. This is the final phrase of this paragraph.";
//List<string> 
foreach (string word in words)
{
    var foundItems = Regex.Matches(paragraph, @"\b" + word + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (foundItems.Count != 0)
    {
        var count = 0;
        var toReplace = 3;
        foreach (Match foudItem in foundItems)
        {
            count++;
            if(count != toReplace)
                continue;

            var regex = $"(^.{{{foudItem.Index}}}){foudItem.Value}(.*)";
            paragraph = Regex.Replace(paragraph, regex, $"$1<strong>{foudItem.Value}</strong>$2");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(paragraph);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(foundItems[0] + " " + foundItems[1]);
}
```